# Dynamic Table View Cells and IBOutlets - Saving Data on From Stepper Inside Cell Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

I have a dynamic tableView with multiple different types of cells.

Of these different types, I have one type of cell that I'm using that will collect 2 different data points I'm trying to capture with the same tableViewCell class using a `UIStepper`.

Code:

```
class DamperGasTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var damperGasLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var valueStepper: UIStepper!

    var valueDouble: Double = 0.0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setValueLabel()
    }

    func setValueLabel () {

        valueLabel.text = String(valueDouble)
    }


    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        valueDouble = Double(valueStepper.value)
        setValueLabel()
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to get the value of the stepper (`valueDouble`) inside of the view controller so I can set it to a different variable.

I'm able to get the value initially when it loads by doing:

```
cellForRowAt - 
cell.valueDouble = self.valueCell
```

But I'm not sure how to go about updating the value when the value is changed when the stepper is pressed.

Comment: You can use a delegation pattern from your cell to your view controller to let the view controller know when the stepper value changes. The view controller can then update your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is that your view controller should tell the cell what it’s initial value is in `cellForRowAt`, and the cell should inform the view controller of changes (so the view controller can update the model), such as via the delegate-protocol pattern:

So consider this model structure:

```
struct DamperGas {
    let name: String
    var value: Double
}
```

And a view controller that calls the cell’s `configure` method in `cellForRowAt`, but also conforms to the cell’s delegate protocol to receive updates:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    private var values: [DamperGas] = ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DamperGasTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DamperGasTableViewCell
        cell.configure(with: values[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: DamperGasTableViewCellDelegate {
    func stepperCell(_ cell: DamperGasTableViewCell, didChangeValue value: Double) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        values[indexPath.row].value = value
    }
}
```

And the cell would define a protocol and then call the delegate when the stepper changes:

```
protocol DamperGasTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func stepperCell(_ cell: DamperGasTableViewCell, didChangeValue value: Double)
}

class DamperGasTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var damperGasLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

    weak var delegate: DamperGasTableViewCellDelegate?

    func configure(with entry: DamperGas, delegate: DamperGasTableViewCellDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        damperGasLabel.text = entry.name
        stepper.value = entry.value
        updateLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        updateLabel()
        delegate?.stepperCell(self, didChangeValue: sender.value)
    }
}

private extension DamperGasTableViewCell {
    func updateLabel() {
        valueLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"
    }
}
```

In this pattern, the cell doesn’t hold any model objects, but rather just accepts input for initial values and sends updates to its delegate, the view controller.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. It wasn't following the correct pattern. I think that may have added to the confusion. Especially since I'm new to this.  

I have a few questions though, or rather I'm mostly just talking out loud as I attempt to walk myself through it.  

Thank you for answering.

Comment: I'm using realm for the data storage, however this view controller is a model popup view, so the data is being passed back and being saved in a method(segue: UIStoryboardSegue).  

So my understanding is the purpose of the struct here is set up the tableViews with index path.  

So in the view controller we are initializing an array of the struct to store the name/label and the value which can then be matched to the cells with indexPath

Comment: I'm not great with parameters. They don't make too much sense to me, but it looks like inside of the cellForRow, we are changing the delegate from the tableView to the cell.  

That way, when the stepper is touched, inside the View Controller knows to tell the Cell Class to handle the event?  

Which is then handled by valueChanged(), and then passed back to the view controller with the protocol method?

Comment: What I don't understand is the private var and extension. They are throwing build errors for me.

Comment: @StonedStudio - “What I don't understand is the private var and extension.” ... The `private` var was just to make it clear that the cell isn’t mucking around with the model directly, but it’s not relevant to this example. E.g., if you’re passing data into this view controller from the proceeding one, you can’t make it `private`. Regarding the extension, you can remove the `private` there, too, if you want. I can’t diagnose what’s going on on the basis of the comments here, and it’s not relevant to the question at hand. In both cases, just remove the `private` if you want.

Comment: Re the “parameters” and the “delegate”, I think you may have misunderstood what’s going on. Don’t confuse the cell’s delegate with the table view’s delegate, as they’re different things. The above assumes `valueChanged` is called on the cell. So the question is how does the cell tell the view controller that `valueChanged` was called and supply the value? In `cellForRowAt`, the table view says “ok, Mr. cell, you have your custom protocol to tell me about changes, so I’ll be your delegate ... that way when `valueChanged` is called, you can call your protocol method to let me know.”

Comment: It makes sense - Basically the Parameters are passing the data from the stepper.value into each other, back into the view controller. It just takes me a minute to follow the inputs around.    

However, there is one new issue I have. The cells are in the 3rd section of the table, and there are cells before these in the above sections. Is there any other way to tap into the cell that was the sender other than indexPath?